# scala mergesort non-exhaustive pattern matching error

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Here is my implementation:

```
def mergesort(xs:List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
  def left(xs:List[Int]) = xs.take(xs.length / 2)
  def right(xs:List[Int]) = xs.drop(xs.length / 2)
  def merge(xs:List[Int], ys:List[Int]):List[Int] = (xs, ys) match {
    case(x::xs, y::ys) if x <= y => x::merge(xs, ys)
    case(x::xs, y::ys) if y < x => y::merge(xs, ys)
    case(Nil, Nil) => List()
    case(Nil, ys) => ys
    case(xs, Nil) => xs
  }

  if (xs.length == 0) {
    List()
  }
  else if (xs.length == 1) {
    xs
  }
  else {
    merge(mergesort(left(xs)), mergesort(right(xs)))
  }
}
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

```
 warning: match is not exhaustive!
missing combination              *           Nil             *             *

  def merge(xs:List[Int], ys:List[Int]):List[Int] = (xs, ys) match {
```

What does this error mean? What combination have I missed?

Comment: I can't get this error pasting your code into the Ammonite REPL using Scala 2.11.8.  What version of Scala are you using?

Comment: IntelliJ complains about lots of "suspicious shadowing" but otherwise it compiles just fine. (Scala 2.11.7)

Comment: @dopatraman I guess you should change the title, it seems like to be just a warning...
BTW: it is quite confusing that you reuse the identifiers of `xs` and `ys` in pattern matching. I doubt it works as you would expect (`case(x::xs, y::ys) ...`). In case you can observe actual error, please also include the input you were tested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern guards (`if x <= y` and `if y < x`) actually stop Scala from checking for exhaustivity, see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5365. So you shouldn't get this warning on this code.

But if the compiler did check (it [might in 2.12](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4929) or further in the future), it would likely not be able to see that these two guards cover all possible cases (without treating this specific case specially or making the language a lot more complex). Removing the second guard would fix the problem in this case.

Comment: If I removed the second guard how would i run `y::merge(xs, ys)` when `y < x` ?

Comment: If you remove the second guard (not the entire `case`), the second `case` will be used whenever the pattern matches and the first guard (`x <= y`) is false, which is the same as you currently have.